# SonarQube API search issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to fetch a list of all issues in my name and having severity as `MAJOR`, `CRITICAL`.

I tried API and it is not accepting two parameters and complain that not supported. Please help how to read list of issues?

I am using reference form below site
http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392181#WebService/api/issues-GetaListofIssues

```
C:\cURL\bin>curl.exe -X GET -v -u admin:admin http://localhost.com:9000/ap
i/issues/search?severities="MAJOR,CRITICAL"&assignees="nits"&pageSize="-1"
```

SONARQUBE 4.4

Comment: Please add: SonarQube version, response content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with execution of `CURL` (not with SonarQube API). `&` is a special character in shell. You should use quotes (`curl params "url"`):

```
curl -X GET -v -u admin:admin "http://localhost.com:9000/api/issues/search?severities=MAJOR,CRITICAL&assignees=nits&pageSize=-1"
```

or escape special characters (`\&`):

```
curl -X GET -v -u admin:admin http://localhost.com:9000/api/issues/search?severities=MAJOR,CRITICAL\&assignees=nits\&pageSize=-1
```

Comment: I have Sonar 4.4 and when ever i add second argument it says command not found... let me run again and post you that result.

Comment: 'assignees' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'pageSize' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.         <======= with and without quote same issue

Comment: You have a problem with special characters in shell. I modified answer.

Comment: Thanks that "url" thing worked earlier I was trying quote in parameters.

Comment: What parameter should we use to fetch records of a specific project?

Comment: Probably `projectKeys` (see [documentation](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/issues))

Answer (score 2):

For a specific project you must use `http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?components=project.key`